# Assistance in showing $\cos(0) = 1$ via definition from Spivak

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, trigonometry, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that $\cos(0) = 1$ via the treatment done in *Spivak's Calculus (2008) - pg 303*. To begin we have two definitions:

> **Defn 1:**   If $-1 \leq x \leq 1$, then $$A(x) = \frac{x\sqrt{1-x^{2}}}{2} + \int_{x}^{1}\sqrt{1-t^{2}}dt$$

> **Defn 2:** If $0 \leq x \leq \pi$, then $\cos(x)$ is the unique number in $[-1,1]$ such that $$A(\cos(x)) = \frac{x}{2}; \\ \sin(x) = \sqrt{1-\cos^{2}(x)}$$

So using these definitions I was attempting to confirm that $\cos(0) = 1$ and then do $\pi$ afterwards. So since $\cos(x)$ is considered a number, I took the following approach:

$$0 = \frac{y\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}{2} + \int_{y}^{1}\sqrt{1-t^{2}}dt$$

where I just let $y = \cos(x)$ as a placeholder. Carrying on:

$$0 = \frac{y\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}{2} - \int_{1}^{y}\sqrt{1-t^{2}}dt$$

Now by the second fundamental theorem of calculus (applied to the integral portion):

$$0 = \frac{y\sqrt{1-y^{2}}}{2} - (\sqrt{1-y^{2}} - 0) \\ 0 = \sqrt{1-y^{2}}(y-2)$$

At this point I am left with $y = \pm 1$ or $y = 2$. Now since $\cos(x)$ is defined to exist only between $[-1,1]$ then $2$ is out of the question, which leaves me with the other case. But I'm having trouble ruling out the case of $-1$. If this is the right approach how can I rule out this other case and conclude $\cos(0) = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $A(1) = 0$, and by definition, $\cos 0$ is the unique number in $[-1,1]$ such that $A(\cos 0) = 0$. So, it follows that $1$ and $\cos 0$ are the same number!

*Added*: In page 305, Spivak defines $\pi$ as
$$\pi := 2\int_{-1}^1 \sqrt{1-t^2}dt,$$
so $A(-1) = \frac{\pi}2$, but the definition of $\cos$ says that $\cos(\pi)$ is the unique number in $[-1,1]$ such that $A(\cos \pi) = \frac{\pi}2$. Again, it follows that $\cos(\pi) = -1$ by the uniqueness.

Comment: Ah...True indeed. I was attempting to do $\cos(\pi) = -1$, but I'm running into difficulty at the moment. Could I do what I attempted above?

Comment: Why do you say $\int_1^y \sqrt{1-t^2}dt = \sqrt{1-y^2}$? The fundamental theorem of calculus says $\int_1^y \sqrt{1-t^2}dt = g(y)-g(1)$, where $g$ is a function such that $g'(t) = \sqrt{1-t^2}$.

Comment: I see what you mean. I made the wrong conclusion that $g(y) = \sqrt{1-y^{2}}$.